# Do you capitalize both parts of a hyphenated word in a title?

Tags: punctuation, capitalization, hyphenation, titles

Do you capitalize both parts of a hyphenated word in a title?

"My Ex-Wife Hates Me"

or

"My Ex-wife Hates Me"

Comment: Just to echo VonC's answer: given the choice, a title like *Co-Founder* feels more appropriate with a capital initial in the second word.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Capitalization of  hyphenated words in general is really more a question of style than anything else.
In other word, choose a rule and be consistent with it:

From [Garbl's writing center](https://web.archive.org/web/20150206062415/http://home.comcast.net/%7Egarbl/stylemanual/c.htm):

> When capitalizing hyphenated words in a title, choose a style and follow it consistently.
>
> Simplest is to capitalize only the first word unless later words are proper nouns or adjectives:
>
> > Unique benefits for part-time violinists,
> > All-American flag-waving techniques.
>
> Second is to capitalize all words except articles, short prepositions and short conjunctions:
>
> > Over-the-Counter Acid Reducers for Sale Here,
> > A Matter-of-Fact Approach to Guitar Tuning,
> > A New Park-and-Ride Lot for Commuters.
>
> Optional exceptions to the second style are to lowercase the word after a prefix unless it is a proper noun or adjective and to lowercase the second word in a spelled out number:
>
> > Anti-intellectual Conduct,
> > Twenty-first Century Values.

---

In your case, since ["ex-" is a prefix](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ex-):

> My Ex-wife Hates Me

Comment: So if one writes "My Ex-Wife Hates Me", it is still correct, just that the optional exceptions mentioned in the answer is not observed?

Comment: @FangJing I suppose so, since all words are capitalized.

Comment: How would you suggest 'add-on' be used here: "Introducing Health-Check - New Add-On to Product X"?

Comment: Given the huge difference between how likely people are to capitalise the second component in ***Ex-wife*** compared to ***Co-Founder***, I think ***choose a rule and be consistent with it*** is terrible advice. Whichever rule you choose and stick to, you'll be swimming against the linguistic tide with much of your text!