# Is it appropriate to use a hyphen in compound adjectives?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it necessary to use a hyphen in writing a compound word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word)

I've searched the web and "English Language & Usage", but am having problems finding the answer to the following question:

Is it appropriate to use a hyphen for compound adjectives consisting of two adjectives having the same, how do I put it, "status"? That is, *grammatically speaking*, they could each stand on their own instead of the compound word. Thus, I'm not talking about words like "well-mannered", but rather words like "thermomechanical/thermo-mechanical" ("thermal" + "mechanical") or
"magnetorheological/magneto-rheological" ("magnetic" + "rheological").

In short, is it "thermomechanical" or "thermo-mechanical"?

Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned above, I couldn't find the answer to this particular question in any general discussion of hyphen usage (such as the question you link to). That is what motivated me to post this one.

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41210/using-hyphenated-words-in-technical-writing). That question was about prefixes, but the same rules should apply. Use your dictionary first and if it offers no help, revert to your style guide.

Comment: From a position of abysmal ignorance, I'd advocate doing so. A hyphen or two in _magnetohydrodynamics_ wouldn't come amiss.