# Capitalisation of hyphenated words in title

Tags: capitalization, hyphenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you capitalize both parts of a hyphenated word in a title?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/460/do-you-capitalize-both-parts-of-a-hyphenated-word-in-a-title)

I contribute to a journal with a policy of capitalisation of the article titles. My title is *Hygro-thermo-mechanical analysis*. Should I say

> *Hygro-Thermo-Mechanical Analysis*

or

> *Hygro-thermo-mechanical Analysis*?