# Hyphenation and capitalization of "Great-Uncle" when signing books to my nephew's son

Tags: capitalization, hyphenation, spacing

When *great-uncle* is used as a common noun, the hyphen and lack of caps make sense. However, when I sign a book to my nephew, is it *Great-Uncle Don, Great-uncle Don*, or perhaps *Great Uncle Don*?

Comment: Your last is a shade boastful: I had a great uncle, and also a great-uncle.

Comment: Related: [Do you capitalize both parts of a hyphenated word in a title?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/460/do-you-capitalize-both-parts-of-a-hyphenated-word-in-a-title)

Answer (score 7):

The general rule is that, in a capitalized hyphenated compound word, both words are normally capitalized if they are of approximately equal significance.

In "great-uncle," "uncle" is the more significant part; "great-" is simply modifying "uncle" after all.

So sign yourself "Great-Uncle Don."

Or, dodge the hyphenation entirely, and sign yourself "*Granduncle* Don."

Comment: In our family  we don't usually say/keep the modifiers and just call all uncles and great-uncles, "*uncle*".  So the book would be signed "Uncle Don"