# Which is the correct way to write "Back-end Engineer"?

Tags: capitalization, compounds, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

On the web, I find the following common ways of punctuating and capitalising "Back-end Engineer" as a job title.

1. Back-End Engineer
2. Back-end Engineer
3. Backend Engineer

Which of these is correct?

Comment: It would normally be written in lower-case letters, as would other forms of engineer. Both "backend" and "back-end" seem common although if you're going by a dictionary, you may find "backend" is not in there.

Comment: This answer may also help with capitalisation https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/460/do-you-capitalize-both-parts-of-a-hyphenated-word-in-a-title

Comment: There is no such thing as correct here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brittanica's own website writes it as

> Backend

[Brittanica's own job ad](https://www.comeet.com/jobs/britannica/95.00D/backend-tech-lead-engineer/AE.81D)