# Correct Capitalisation of Hyphenated English Title

Tags: capitalization, titles, headline-case

I have a presentation with one of the slides titled

> Results: limited-data in-the-wild semantic segmentation

What would be the correct way to capitalise this title? https://capitalizemytitle.com/style/APA/ recommends either

> Results: Limited-Data In-The-Wild Semantic Segmentation

or

> Results: Limited-Data In-the-Wild Semantic Segmentation

with the latter of the two being the one I originally used. However, this seems to be in conflict with the recommendations from [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized), which say words like "in" or "the" should never be capitalised.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you capitalize both parts of a hyphenated word in a title?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/460/do-you-capitalize-both-parts-of-a-hyphenated-word-in-a-title) Capitalisation is a matter of style but one valid method is "to capitalize all words except articles, short prepositions and short conjunctions" in hyphenated expressions.

Comment: Results: Limited Data-in-the-Wild Semantic Segmentation.  Do not capitalize in and the/